# Visual Studios Unit Tests passing locally, "Not Executed" on build server

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I am currently running into an issue with Unit tests passing locally, but getting reported "failed" test cases on our build servers. Locally, I am running win7 VS2013 test agent and the build servers are running win8 VS2013 test agent.

Firstly, all our tests are passing on our local machines, so we are having trouble reproducing the problems on the build server. Secondly, on the build servers, the tests are reporting that they aren't being executed, but based on the console output as well as some coverage information reported, we can see that the tests are actually running (which is a mystery to us).

We have attempted the tests locally and all our local machines will pass, but all our server machines will not pass certain tests. Also we have attempted to rollback to a previous state on the build server that was passing, but even that has not worked. We have already attempted a clean build/rebooting of the build machines, but nothing has helped so far as the tests are still reported as "not executed" (console outputs suggest that it is running since our debugging information is being printed). The tests are running in parallel on the build server, but that shouldn't be an issue as it was running fine before.

UPDATE: After doing some debugging, we are having trouble with Singleton Classes. The odd situation is some of our other test suites use the same singleton class and doesn't have any problems on the build server, while other suites will. 
We have removed all tests but one using this singleton class, but it still reports as "Not executed".

anyone running into this issue or have a solution or a suggestion on where to look?
-L

Comment: Do you have multiple build definitions? I've seen an issue before where multiple builds run simultaneously and get weird outcomes.

Comment: is vs2013 installed on the build server? if yes what happens when you try to run the tests ? if no, install the community edition